# Get length of text area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add below my textarea the length of the written text.

For this purpose I have defined a `span` element to write my characters.

However, I currently get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: len is not defined

Find below my viable example:

```js
$(".form-control.description").keyup(this.countCharacters.bind(this))


function countCharacters() {
  len = $(".form-control.rigDesc").val().length
  $(".remainChar").html("#" + len);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row" align="left">
  <div class="col-7">
    <textarea class="form-control rigDesc" rows="4" id="comment" placeholder="Describe..."></textarea>
    <span class="remainChar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions how to capture the length of the textarea field?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the class `description` in your `textarea` as you have used `$(".form-control.description")` in your `keyup` event which seeks for the element with class `form-control` and `description` so you need to add `description` class in your `textarea`.

```js
$(".form-control.description").keyup(this.countCharacters.bind(this))

function countCharacters() {
  len = $(".form-control.rigDesc").val().length
  $(".remainChar").html("#" + len);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row" align="left">
  <div class="col-7">
    <textarea class="form-control description rigDesc" rows="4" id="comment" placeholder="Describe..."></textarea>
    <span class="remainChar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more accuracy and preventing unintentional error you can use `$("textarea.form-control.description")` to make sure the `keyup` event is only for `textarea` with class `form-control` and `description`.

```js
$("textarea.form-control.description").keyup(this.countCharacters.bind(this))

function countCharacters() {
  len = $(".form-control.rigDesc").val().length
  $(".remainChar").html("#" + len);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row" align="left">
  <div class="col-7">
    <textarea class="form-control description rigDesc" rows="4" id="comment" placeholder="Describe..."></textarea>
    <span class="remainChar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was binding the keyup to the wrong selector. I have fixed that and also ensured that len is a local and not global variable. See below:

```js
$(".form-control").keyup(this.countCharacters.bind(this))


function countCharacters() {
  var len = $(".form-control.rigDesc").val().length;
  $(".remainChar").html("#" + len);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group row" align="left">
  <div class="col-7">
    <textarea class="form-control rigDesc" rows="4" id="comment" placeholder="Describe..."></textarea>
    <span class="remainChar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have a input element with class `form-control` this will be misleading at that time